# What uses Passbook's Logging Endpoint?

Tags: ios, ios6, passbook

I'm just beginning the implementation of my Web Service for passbook.

In the docs I see there's an optional endpoint for logs, but don't understand what uses/consumes this endpoint?

As far as I can tell, it's only used by humans who wish to check the logs.

For clarity, Apple's docs say the logs should be accessible via a

> POST request to webServiceURL /version /log

but I can't see why we couldn't use a GET request to webServiceURL/version/myAppsLogs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the specification, Passbook will POST a JSON document to your logging endpoint. GET wouldn't allow submitting data. This JSON document will only have one key "logs" which is an array of strings. You need to respond only with an HTTP 200 status.

A sample communication would look like this:

```
POST /yourwebServiceURL/v1/log HTTP/1.1
Host: yourserver
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 83

{
  "logs" : [
    "log message 1",
    "log message 2",
    "log message n"
  ]
}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Close
```

Answer (score 2):

Passbook itself uses this url if it finds an error in the pass, or in your implementation of the api. I definitely recommend logging everything that comes through this url, the errors are  pretty comprehensive, and it helped me find some problems I didn't know that I had.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the

POST request to webServiceURL /version /log

so Passbook can upload logs to your server.

The GET call to fetch the logs depends on what you do when you receive the logs in the POST call. For example if you save them on a file, you can let the user (probably an admin user) download the file or a part of it.

If you save the each POST action on a row on a database, you can send the last n rows...

Comment: Ah thanks. I wonder why this was voted down? I'll start implementation soon and confirm what you've said and mark it as an answer. Thanks for your help!